# How to convert from a float to 4 bytes in Java?

Tags: java, byte, converters

I have not been able to convert something like this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 12, 24, 19, 17};
```

into something like this:

```
float myfloatvalue = ?;
```

Could someone please give me an example?

Also how to turn that float back to bytes?

Comment: Are those bytes the bits of a float representation, or are they a 4-byte integer?

Comment: And what order are they in? Is 12 the most significant or the least significant 8 bits?

Comment: They are just random byte values that i typed out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Bytes to floats / ints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513498/java-bytes-to-floats-ints)

Comment: The exact values don't matter. What do the bytes represent? In words, how do the bytes represent a float?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From `byte[]` -> `float`, you could do:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 12, 24, 19, 17};
float myfloatvalue = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getFloat();
```

Here is an alternative to using `ByteBuffer.allocate` for converting `float` -> `byte[]`:

```
int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(myFloat);
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
bytes[0] = (byte)(bits & 0xff);
bytes[1] = (byte)((bits >> 8) & 0xff);
bytes[2] = (byte)((bits >> 16) & 0xff);
bytes[3] = (byte)((bits >> 24) & 0xff);
```

Comment: Minor point, ByeBuffer encodes in big endian and the current example is in little endian. Making them match would be great! Ty!

Answer (score 38):

## `byte[]` -> `float`

With [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getFloat()):

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{12, 24, 19, 17};
float f =  ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getFloat();
```

## `float` -> `byte[]`

Reverse operation (knowing the result of above):

```
float f =  1.1715392E-31f;
byte[] b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(f).array();  //[12, 24, 19, 17]
```

Comment: That helps and what about turning that float back into bytes

Comment: +1 honestly, ByteBuffer is an under-used, and under-appreciated class.

Comment: @user1395152: please, read the documentation of `ByteBuffer`. And see my update.

Comment: +1 You may need to set the byte order with `.order(ByteBuffer.LITTE_ENDIAN)` as well.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Came handy when needed. Beauty is that it works even with `ByteBuffer` of Google's protobuf. Many many thanks!

Comment: this should be: ByteBuffer.wrap(myBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();

Answer (score 2):

Convert the bytes to an int and use Float.intBitsToFloat()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)