# Mapping C structs in Scala

Tags: c, scala, parsing, scodec

What is the best way to read and write C-styled byte stuctures in Scala, like this:

```
    struct account {
            int id;
            char[10] data1;
            char[10] data2;
            float dataFloat;
    };
```

There's unpack function in Python, to interpret strings as packed binary data. But I can't find any analogue in Scala.

What is standart way for such a mapping in Scala? Read bytes one by one is very unsufficiant. The protocol I need to parse comes back fromk 1980s and contains different fields (short, int, float) so read it byte-by-byte will be very unsufficient.

Answer (score 5):

http://scodec.org/ [(code)](https://github.com/scodec/scodec) might be what you want. Some examples in this video: [Introduction to Shapeless with applications from scodec](https://youtu.be/eNJ6ZbbrP2A)

Example from the docs: Automatic case class binding is supported via Shapeless HLists:

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)

val pointCodec = (int8 :: int8 :: int8).as[Point]

val encoded: Attempt[BitVector] = pointCodec.encode(Point(-5, 10, 1))
// Successful(BitVector(24 bits, 0xfb0a01))

val decoded: Attempt[DecodeResult[Point]] = pointCodec.decode(hex"0xfb0a01".bits)
// Successful(DecodeResult(Point(-5,10,1),BitVector(empty)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As Scala can still rely on the java classes :

You are of course using an `InputStream` to read the bytes, 
Converting the `byte[]` to a string should be the same as Java using `new String(byte[])`.

Converting the float is another problem answered [in this SO question about byte to float conversion in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4513578/105104).

An easier way would be to use the [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which has a convenient [getFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getFloat()) method

Comment: Thank you! Very nice pure language variant.